# Align three divs horizontally

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, alignment

```
[Button 1] ["OR"] [Button]
```

How can I to align 3 divs, first div contains Button, 2nd div contains paragraph, 3 div contains list with a button inside.

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div style="width: 50%;padding: 0;margin: 0">
    <button type="submit" style="width: 90% !important;  margin: 20px auto !important;"><p class="register-text">Register</p></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p style="padding-top: 15px">OR</p>
  </div>
  <div class="eauth" style="width: 50%;padding: 0;margin: 0" id="w0">
    <ul class="eauth-list">
      <button style="width:90%" type="button" data-eauth-service="facebook">
             <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i><span>Sign-in with Facebook</span>
       </button>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/e5chxu7g/)

Comment: Do you HAVE to use inline styles or you can use a separate CSS stylesheet ? And i see that you are using Bootstrap col classes, do you have bootstrap added to your project ?

Comment: Specify which version of bootstrap you're using, if you're using BS4 then you're in luck you can simply use the vertical alignment helper https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/vertical-align/ else you're gonna have to use flex boxes https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/

Comment: As Mihai said. Are you even using bootstrap actually? Didn't see you importing the bootstrap style.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code here:**

If you use bootstrap include the bootstrap CSS and add parent simple classes `<div class="itemWrap">` to `<div class="d-flex align-items-center">` then not needed

```
.itemWrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-top;
}
```

**Don't needed avobe code if you add bootstrap CSS**

```css
.itemWrap {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-top;
}
.dvi1,
.dvi2,
.dvi3 {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.div2 {
    background: gray;
    padding: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    padding: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="itemWrap">
    <div class="div1" style="width: 50%;padding: 0;margin: 0">
        <button type="submit" style="width: 90% !important;  margin: 20px auto !important;">
            <p class="register-text">Register</p>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        <p>Lorem ipsum, or lipsum as it is sometimes known, is dummy text used in laying out print, graphic or web designs. The passage is attributed to an unknown typesetter in the 15th</p>
    </div>
    <div class="div3" style="width: 50%;padding: 0;margin: 0" id="w0">
        <ul class="eauth-list">
            <li>
                <button style="width:90%" type="button" data-eauth-service="facebook">
                    <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i><span>Sign-in with Facebook</span>
                </button>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="button" data-eauth-service="facebook">
                    <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i><span>Sign-in with Facebook</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" data-eauth-service="facebook">
                    <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i><span>Sign-in with Facebook</span>
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try like this,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Button1</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Text</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Button2</div>
</div>
```

With this , all 3 elements will be inside same row and I separate them in equal columns. You can make sure that div with row class will be a full width and then your buttons and text will share row's width equally and will align horizontally as you mentioned

Comment: @DavidThomas Op asked *How can I to align 3 divs, first div contains Button, 2nd div contains paragraph, 3 div contains list with a button inside.* This isn't complete answer, but just the boilderplate

Comment: @DavidThomas added a small description, how's now?

Comment: Thank you, that's definitely an improvement.

Answer (score -1):

if you're using bootstrap 4 then add `row` class to parent class

```css
.row p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row align-items-center">
  <div class="col-md-5" style="">
    <button type="submit" style="width: 90% !important;  margin: 20px auto !important;"><p class="register-text">Register</p></button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <p style="">OR</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5" class="eauth" style="" id="w0">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
      <li><button style="width:90%" type="button" data-eauth-service="facebook">
             <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i><span>Sign-in with Facebook</span>
       </button></li>
      <li><button style="width:90%" type="button" data-eauth-service="facebook">
             <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i><span>Sign-in with Facebook</span>
       </button></li>
       <li><button style="width:90%" type="button" data-eauth-service="facebook">
             <i class="icon icon-facebook"></i><span>Sign-in with Facebook</span>
       </button></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Take look at [DEMO CODE](http://%20https://jsfiddle.net/5xk068ae/), I have removed extra html tags